# How to open magit-status in full window

Tags: emacs, magit

I am using Magit to work with git in emacs. I have bound magit-status to a key, but every time I hit the key it opens in a split in lower half of the window and i have to hit C-x 1 to get it into a full window. How can I make it open in a full window by default?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```lisp
(setq magit-status-buffer-switch-function 'switch-to-buffer)
```

or via customize:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `magit-status-buffer-switch-function` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Note that with current Magit, new buffer behavior is handled by `magit-display-buffer-function`.

Comment: That changes the command to `M-x` `customize-variable` `RET` `magit-display-buffer-function` `RET`.

Answer (score 23):

For newer versions of Magit you can use this [sanctioned](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1953#issuecomment-221134023) snippet:

`(setq magit-display-buffer-function #'magit-display-buffer-fullframe-status-v1)`

I combine it with this to get a zen-like full window Git status after switching projects:

`(setq projectile-switch-project-action 'magit-status)`

Comment: That's actually the full frame, for full window, it's magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1.

Comment: Thanks for adding the neat projectile addition!

Comment: Anyway to keep the same buffers open upon exit?

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to achieve this:

`(add-to-list 'same-window-regexps "\*magit: .*\*")`

Answer (score 4):

This solution has the advantage that you can kill the fullscreen buffer in `quit-window` style:

```
(defadvice magit-status (around magit-fullscreen activate)
  (window-configuration-to-register :magit-fullscreen)
  ad-do-it
  (delete-other-windows))

(defadvice magit-mode-quit-window (after magit-restore-screen activate)
  "Restores the previous window configuration and kills the magit buffer"
  (jump-to-register :magit-fullscreen))

(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "q") 'magit-mode-quit-window)
```

If you have an older version of magit then you might need to rename `magit-mode-quit-window` to `magit-quit-window`.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```lisp
(defun my-magit-status ()
  "Don't split window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((pop-up-windows nil))
    (call-interactively 'magit-status)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Note! Newer versions of magit use the function, `magit-display-buffer-function`, and this can be harnessed to get the same behaviour. The following snippet will give you the desired, fullscreen, magit bounty.

```
(defun display-buffer-full-screen (buffer alist)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (set-window-dedicated-p nil nil)
  (set-window-buffer nil buffer)
  (get-buffer-window buffer))

(setq magit-display-buffer-function
      (lambda (buffer)
        (if magit-display-buffer-noselect
            (magit-display-buffer-traditional buffer)
          (display-buffer buffer '(display-buffer-full-screen)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

For Magit v2.90.1, the correct answer didn't suit me. With the line below it achieved the best results.

```
(setq magit-display-buffer-function 'magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1)
```

Other display functions can be found by the prefix `magit-display-buffer-`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to customize the variable `display-buffer-alist`.

If all you want is `magit`, you can do this:

```
(customize-set-variable
     'display-buffer-alist
     '(("\\*magit: .*" display-buffer-same-window)))
```

Comment: Nice, but for recent versions of magit you need to remove the leading asterisk in the condition: `"magit: .*"`